# Bind text input to value of observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an observable array that the user can add or remove items to. In addition I have one text input, and a DIV for each element in the array. When the user clicks on one of the DIVs I add the class "selected" to the DIV.
I want to bind the one input with the DIV that has the selected class.

Knockout:

```
self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);

self.addTask = function() {
    self.tasks.push(
        {
            id: "1",
            content: ""
        }
    );
}
```

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: tasks">
    <div class="wrapper" data-bind="text: content" class="selected"></div>
    <div class="wrapper" data-bind="text: content"></div>
    <div class="wrapper" data-bind="text: content"></div>
</div>
<label>Edit Task:</label> <input type="text" data-bind="value: content">
```

So basically every time one of the DIVs is selected I want to be able to updated the content parameter of the observable array that relates to the selected div, via the input field.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create an observable that holds the index value of the selected task and bind your input accordingly:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: tasks">
    <div class="wrapper" data-bind="text: content, 
      click: $root.selectTask, 
      css: {'selected': $root.selectedIndex() === $index()}">
    </div>
</div>
<label>Edit Task:</label> 
<input type="text" data-bind="value: tasks()[selectedIndex()].content">
```

You can see that the input value is bound to the content from one of the values in your tasks array. The selected class is also bound to that observable in a conditional.

Then your model would look like this (I defaulted the selectedIndex value to 0):

```
function Model() {
    var self = this;
    this.tasks = ko.observableArray();
    this.addTask = function(id, content) {
        self.tasks.push(
        {
            id: ko.observable(id),
            content: ko.observable(content)
        });
    };
    this.selectedIndex = ko.observable(0);
    this.selectTask = function(task) {
        self.selectedIndex(self.tasks.indexOf(task));
    };
}
```

The selectTask function gets the new index based on where the user clicked and updates the observable. And all the DOM updating is taken care of for you after that.

Here's an example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MD35J/

Comment: Great solution! thank you very much for taking the time providing a clear solution with example code!